# Install oauth.so in heroku

Tags: heroku, uservoice

We are using uservoice sdk (https://developer.uservoice.com/docs/api/php-sdk/) in our project & this one depends on oauth.so lib.

Can anyone suggest how we can install oauth.so in heroku as we are trying to deploy our application there & build keep failing due to missing dependency.

We have tried process described in https://gist.github.com/pedro/1288447 but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `oauth` extension is available now: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/582